# Tkinter3 - Asking pointer position on the window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I already know about '`winfo_pointerx()`' and '`winfo_pointery()'` but these functions give the position of pointer on the whole screen. I want to know if pointer is on the window or not. And I thought a function like that could help me. But maybe there is an easier one! Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if pointer is on the window or not

If I understand the goal you are trying to achieve, you can use the right [events and bind](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) them to your mouse as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MousePointerInsideOrOutsideWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):       
        master.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: print("Mouse pointer INSIDE main window"))
        master.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: print("Mouse pointer OUTSIDE main window"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
   root=tk.Tk()
   app = MousePointerInsideOrOutsideWindow(root)
   root.mainloop()
```

You chose the `Enter` and `Leave` events to know if the mouse pointer, respectively, enters into or leaves the main window of your GUI.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know much about OOP yet. Could you please write without classes maybe?

Comment: And hey my name is Bilal :)

Comment: @mbilal25tr All you need is the two `master.bind` lines, with `master` being your `Tk` window.

Comment: @Billal BEGUERADJ A question. 'app = MousePointerInsideOrOutsideWindow(root)'
 Will that put the class on work?

Comment: Done! I realized that I didn't have to write the code in a class or function.